# Click table row triggers checkbox event with tr row under it

Tags: jquery, html

I have a working solution but I want to improve it. When a tr row is clicked then the adjacent checkbox is toggled. In this table though, if a user clicks the row below it with the "Sub data" then it would also toggle the checkbox above it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.record_table tr').click(function(event) {
    //alert('function runs twice');
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="record_table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Sub data</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Sub data</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Sub data</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8vb374az/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you could put a class on the sub-level `tr` elements which raised a click event on the previous `tr`, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.record_table tr').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      $(':checkbox', this).prop('checked', function(i, c) { return !c; });
    }
  });
  
  $('.record_table tr.sub').click(function(e) {
    $(this).prev('tr').click();
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="record_table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Sub data</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Sub data</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub">
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Sub data</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One line addition seems to handle it, `$(this).prev().find('input').click();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.record_table tr').click(function(event) {
    //alert('function runs twice');
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
      $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
      $(this).prev().find('input').click();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="record_table">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Sub data</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Sub data</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <p>Sub data</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```